# step-by-step upgradation from a r3 corda application from v4.3 to 4.4

Tags: blockchain, corda

Can someone explain a step by step upgradation from r3 corda release version **4.3** to **4.4** ?

I need to know if changing the platform version is required or not for upgrading to v4.4.

In the documentation , I am quite confused like which all files needs to be upgraded with new version,like corda jar files,quasar files .

Can someone brief me in this ?

Comment: Are you interested in upgrading the node or cordapp?

Comment: @AshutoshMeher Hi. I basically want to upgrade the cordapp-example that is inside samples-4.3. The parties A,B and C need to run on corda release v4.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading cordapp from 4.3 to 4.4 is pretty simple.

Just update the corda and corda-core dependencies from 4.3 to 4.4

```
cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-core:$corda_release_version"
cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda:$corda_release_version"
```

Since new API's are introduced in 4.4 the platformVersion has also been updated from 5 to 6. Consider updating the platformVersion if you are using the new API's in your cordapp. To know more about minimum/ target platform versions [refer here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.0/design/targetversion/design.html#definitions)

**Note:**

You will find that the 4.4 cordapp template has the below update:

```
cordaCompile "$corda_release_group:corda-core:$corda_release_version"
```

has been update to

```
cordaCompile "$corda_core_release_group:corda-core:$corda_core_release_version"
```

Currently, both the release groups refer to `net.corda` however, `corda_core_release_group` was added in-line with the new open-core design approach adopted starting 4.4. Consider using this going forward.

Comment: Thanks Ashutosh, that worked fine. Able to upgrade the cordapp.. as well as for the nodes,I have refered to the documentation, draining of nodes,changing of corda jar files and undraining again to complete the upgradation. Thanks for your quick response..